# What can I add to my query to total up two rows?

Tags: sql

I have the below query and results. What can I add to this query to combine the calories for people with the same name? For example, Dave's total should be 3045+3129 to show 6174.

```
SELECT 
    likes.*, beer.cal, (beer.cal * 21) AS 'Drink 3 in a Week'
FROM
    likes
        INNER JOIN
    beer ON likes.beer = beer.beer;



**name  beer    cal    Drink 3 in a Week**
dave    bud     145     3045
dave    coors   149     3129
gary    miller  143     3003
linda   coors   149     3129
mike    bud     145     3045
mike    miller  143     3003
sally   coors   149     3129
sally   miller  143     3003
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is missing the underlying table structures, sample data, and a desired output. You will have a better experience here if you read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your questions with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window funtion

```
SELECT 
    likes.*, beer.cal, 
    SUM(beer.cal * 21) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME) AS 'Drink 3 in a Week'
FROM
    likes
        INNER JOIN
    beer ON likes.beer = beer.beer;
```

Another option is group by.

Comment: ty! if I wanted to use group by where would I add it? and group by what?

Comment: group by Name and have subquery result joined with main table.

Comment: I got it! Thank you, Sir! Seeing you add the 'SUM' in there and mentioning the 'Group by' helped a lot.

Comment: If my answer helped you then please upvote it or makr as answered.